# SQL query between strings representing version numbers

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that goes like this:

```
select v FROM v.rsversion between 'minVer' and 'maxVer';
```

Where the `version` is expressed as a string of format `x.y.z`

This will return fine all existing versions between 0.2.0 and 0.2.9 
but will return nothing if the range is 0.2.0 and 0.2.10

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I'd suggest storing the version numbers in separate fields for Major, Minor, Build and Rev.  Then you can do actual numeric comparisons (albeit a little tricky).  The "0.2.0.0" (or whatever) is basically just a display format that should be calculated from the version fields.

Comment: What database are you using? Add a corresponding tag to the question. In SQL Server you can use built-in `PARSENAME` function to parse strings in format `w.x.y.z`, but better store the numeric values in separate columns.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the best approach is to store the version numbers in separate fields for Major, Minor, Build and Rev. Since I have to update my schema I will do this.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @jdl134679: the numeric comparison isn't that "tricky" actually if you have the version as three numbers: `where (major,minor,patch) between (0,2,1) and (0,2,11)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Postgres you could do this by splitting up the version into three numbers and then compare those numbers. For other DBMS you would need to find a different way of splitting a string like `0.2.1` into three numbers.

```
with rsversion (v) as (
  values 
     -- only here for sample data
     ('0.2.0'), ('0.2.1'), ('0.2.2'), ('0.2.10'), ('0.2.12'), 
     ('0.3.0'), ('0.3.1'), ('0.3.2'), ('0.3.4')
), numeric_version (v, major, minor, patch) as (
  select v, 
         split_part(v,'.', 1)::int, 
         split_part(v,'.', 2)::int, , 
         split_part(v,'.', 3)::int
   from rsversion
)
select v 
FROM numeric_version 
where (major,minor,patch) between (0,2,1) and (0,2,11)
```

The above prints:

```
v     
------
0.2.1 
0.2.2 
0.2.10
```

---

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/403d2/2

Comment: Thanx, this is great!

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working as designed is because 0.2.0 and 0.2.x are not literal numbers, so if you are trying to do a string comparison it's looking at each incremented character and comparing them.

So 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.10, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, etc is how it's arranging the strings.

You may be able to make this work by adding a leading 0 to the third part of the string 0.2.00, 0.2.01, 0.2.02, etc if that is possible to do for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? I'm assuming your version will always be in a similar format and that your minVer and maxVer are stored as text.

```
WITH
DATA AS
(
SELECT  whatever other data you require,
    SUBSTRING(v.rsversion FROM '^[0-9]+.[0-9]+'), '.', '')::decimal     as version_part_one,
    SUBSTRING(v.rsversion FROM '[0-9]+$')::decimal              as version_part_two

FROM    v
)

SELECT  d.whatever other data you require

FROM    data d

    WHERE   d.version_part_one >= SUBSTRING(minVer FROM '^[0-9]+.[0-9]+')::decimal
    AND
    d.version_part_two >= SUBSTRING(minVer FROM '.[0-9]+$')::decimal
    AND
    d.version_part_one <= SUBSTRING(minVer FROM '^[0-9]+.[0-9]+')::decimal
    AND
    d.version_part_two <= SUBSTRING(maxVer FROM '.[0-9]+$')::decimal
```

You can change the name of the CTE if you're feeling more creative...